# How to start a query activity using the API / DOTNET

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, query, c#

I have this method:

```
    protected void PerformQuery()
    {
        string sStatus = "";
        String requestId = "";
        string sOverallStatus = "";
        string sOverallStatusMessage = "";

        QueryDefinition qd = new QueryDefinition();
        qd.Name = "SentEmails";
        qd.CustomerKey = "SentEmails";

        PerformResult[] results = client.Perform(new PerformOptions(), "start", new APIObject[] { qd }, out sOverallStatus, out sOverallStatusMessage, out requestId);

        DisplayPerformResults(sStatus, results);
    }
```

But the result is an Error:

Overall Status: Error

Number of Results: 1

Status Message: Exception occurred during [Schedule::Start] ErrorID = 80779739

Comment: Are you looking to execute a SOQL using .Net and process those query results?

Comment: I assume this is related to ExactTarget/MarketingCloud. I've added the tag for this.

Comment: in ExactTarget/MarketingCloud I have a Query with CustomerKey = "SentEmails" which writes to a DataExtension, and I want to start this query using an API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: You need to retrieve the ObjectID of the QueryDefinition first. You can't just perform the QueryDefinition using the CustomerKey.

```
    protected string RetriveQueryID(string sQeryDefKey)
    {
        string sObjectId = "";
        txtResponse.Text = "";

        string sStatus = "";
        String requestId = null;

        SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
        sfp.Property = "CustomerKey";
        sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
        sfp.Value = new string[] { sQeryDefKey };

        RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
        rr.ObjectType = "QueryDefinition";
        rr.Properties = new String[] { "ObjectID" };
        rr.Filter = sfp;

        APIObject[] objs = null;

        try
        {
            sStatus = client.Retrieve(rr, out requestId, out objs);
            sObjectId = objs[0].ObjectID;
            txtResponse.Text = sObjectId;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            txtResponse.Text = e.ToString();
        }

        return sObjectId;
    }

    protected void PerformQuery(string sQeryDefKey)
    {
        txtResponse.Text = "";

        string sStatus = "";
        String requestId = "";
        string sOverallStatus = "";
        string sOverallStatusMessage = "";

        QueryDefinition qd = new QueryDefinition();
        qd.ObjectID = RetriveQueryID(sQeryDefKey);
        //qd.Name = sQeryDefKey;
        //qd.CustomerKey = sQeryDefKey;

        PerformResult[] results = client.Perform(new PerformOptions(), "start", new APIObject[] { qd }, out sOverallStatus, out sOverallStatusMessage, out requestId);

        DisplayPerformResults(sOverallStatus, results);
    }
```

Comment: Why not just update your question with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page on the Help site:

[Performing a Query Activity Using the SOAP Web Service API](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/performing_a_query_activity_using_the_soap_web_service_api/)

Here's a sample SOAP envelope that I executed successfully. NOTE: You need to retrieve the ObjectID of the QueryDefinition first.  You can't just perform the QueryDefinition using the CustomerKey.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Perform</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:bf68161e-a8d0-4e8f-a2d4-2bf168a12b93</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-03-02T15:07:51.991Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-03-02T15:12:51.991Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-f71147d1-508a-4a87-aa13-bfc8b9da4a38-27">
            <o:Username><!-- Removed--></o:Username>
            <o:Password><!-- Removed--></o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
            <SendResponseTo>
               <ResponseType>email</ResponseType>
               <ResponseAddress>aspriggs@degdigital.com</ResponseAddress>
               <RespondWhen>Always</RespondWhen>
               <IncludeResults>true</IncludeResults>
               <IncludeObjects>true</IncludeObjects>
            </SendResponseTo>
            <ConversationID>4e13ac98-63f8-4d23-ad5a-60e5eef7eb4b</ConversationID>
            <SequenceCode>1</SequenceCode>
            <CallsInConversation>1</CallsInConversation>
            <RequestType>Asynchronous</RequestType>
         </Options>
         <Action>Start</Action>
         <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
               <ObjectID>86597061-370c-4608-b48f-3aa963d2d963</ObjectID>
            </Definition>
         </Definitions>
      </PerformRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

UPDATE: Retrieve QueryDefinition ObjectID:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:16b5bc0e-7c78-421d-8958-f91312b23ed1</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-03-02T17:21:01.387Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-03-02T17:26:01.387Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-d4b6a237-b813-439d-8c6f-fe5ad929dd8e-3">
            <o:Username><!-- Removed--></o:Username>
            <o:Password><!-- Removed--></o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
               <ClientID>BUSINESS UNIT MID GOES HERE</ClientID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>QueryDefinition</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
            <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
               <Property>CustomerKey</Property>
               <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
               <Value>EXTERNAL KEY GOES HERE</Value>
            </Filter>
            <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
            <Retrieves />
         </RetrieveRequest>
      </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I find that the SOAP envelopes that are available in the examples and [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Documentation/APIStarterKits/SOAPv3.zip)  (direct .ZIP download) are the best way to form the API calls -- in whatever dev environment.

Comment: Thank you, i understand. Do you know how to retrieve the ObjectID of the QueryDefinition using C#

Comment: Updated my example above to include the QueryDefinition retrieve SOAP envelope.

Comment: Great, Thank you! I guess there are no equivalent set of examples in C#.

Comment: How do you construct those SOAP envelopes? is there a tool you can recommend?

Comment: These SOAP envelopes are captured from the C# calls I'm doing in LINQPad.